# How to align offset in Flutter

Tags: flutter, offset

I have this menu on the floating button, but I could not align it correctly.

I want it to show directly above the floating button and centered this is my current offset and also the photo of it. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4b6b.jpg).

I want the pop up menu to be like this on picture 2

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czR3q.png)

This is the source code of the pop up menu

```
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: myPopMenu(context),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNav(
            onChange: (a) {
                Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (c) => AppPage(initialPage: a,)),
                    (route) => false);
            },
        ),
    );
}


Widget myPopMenu(BuildContext context) {

    return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            cardColor: Colors.white60,
        ),
        child: PopupMenuButton(
            offset: const Offset(-90, 100),
            icon: Image.asset('assets/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.cover, height: 40),
            onCanceled: () {
                setState(() {
                    isClicked = false;
                });
            },
            onSelected: (value) {
                setState(() {
                    isClicked = false;
                });

                print('pop up clicked');
                if (value == 0) {
                    alertRate();
                } else if (value == 1){
                    alertServices();
                }else if (value == 2) {
                    alertAdditonalInfo();
                }else if (value == 3){
                    alertReport();
                }
            },
            itemBuilder: (context) {
                setState(() {
                    isClicked = true;
                });

                return [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'Rate & Review',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                        ),
                        value: 0,
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        height: 4,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 2,
                            color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'Edit Available Services',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                        ),
                        value: 1,
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        height: 4,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 2,
                            color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'Edit Social Accounts',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                        ),
                        value: 2,
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        height: 4,
                        child: Container(
                            height: 2,
                            color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                                'Report an Issue',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                        ),
                        value: 3,
                    ),
                ];
            }),
    );
}
```

Comment: Just for confirmation what you want is to center the floating action button on the bottom nav right?

Comment: no, I want to centre the menu of the floating action button , it is too low I want it to be above the bottom nav bar , I will provide a pic of what I want to make it clear

Comment: It is suggested to add the code you implemented presently, which gives the result you showed in the first pic. That will help understand what exactly could be done there to move it up.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, just added the code , I hope it helps

Comment: Isn't there a name for such linear code that goes over 115 lines? Isn't there is better way to do it, by splitting it up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use a dialog.

Here is demo code:

Just call this in your function:

```
Future<void> _displayDialog() async {
await showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white60,
      elevation: 5.0,
      children: [
        SimpleDialogOption(
          onPressed: () {
            //  Do Something
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Text(
            'Rate & Review',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        const Divider(
            color: Colors.black,
            thickness: 2.0,
            endIndent: 16.0,
            indent: 16.0),
        SimpleDialogOption(
          onPressed: () {
            //  Do Something
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Text(
            'Edit Available Services',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        const Divider(
            color: Colors.black,
            thickness: 2.0,
            endIndent: 16.0,
            indent: 16.0),
        SimpleDialogOption(
          onPressed: () {
            //  Do Something
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Text(
            'Edit Social Accounts',
             textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        const Divider(
            color: Colors.black,
            thickness: 2.0,
            endIndent: 16.0,
            indent: 16.0),
        SimpleDialogOption(
          onPressed: () {
            //  Do Something
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Text(
            'Report an Issue',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);}
```

[image]

Comment: it gives me an error , I updated the code can you check it again please?

Comment: call this function in your Floating action button like that   `onPressed: _displayDialog`,

Comment: Thank you so much it did work , but it is way up  , I need it to be just like the second picture